# minimum number of adjacent swaps to remove any instances of "ab" in a string

Tags: algorithms

How can I get started at finding a recursive/dynamic solution to the problem?

For example, how many adjacent swaps is at least needed to convert the given string `abaaccbabaabcab` (representing all other characters as `c`) to one without any instances of "ab"? It's elusive for me to come up with a way of breaking the problem into (independent) sub-problems.

For strings consisting of only `a`s and `b`s, the problem reduces to taking all `b`s before `a`s, but it becomes complicated with other characters involved.

PS: Can we assert that in at least one scenario of minimum swapping, swaps do not go beyond any block of `c...c`, where ... simply consists of a pile of `a`s and `b`s? In that case, `a`s either place after `b`s, or before first `c`, depending on which is closer. Vice versa for `b`s. I'm not sure if it helps though.

Thanks for your help.